# Neural Network Output :Scaling the output range

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

The output layer of my neural network (3 layered) is using sigmoid as activation which outputs only in range [0-1]. However, if I want to train it for outputs that are beyond [0-1], say in thousands, what should I do?

For example if I want to train

input ----> output

0 0 ------> 0

0 1 ------> 1000

1000 1 ----> 1

1 1 -------> 0

My program works for AND, OR, XOR etc. As input output are all in binary.

There were some suggestion to use,

Activation:

---

y = lambda*(abs(x)*1/(1+exp(-1*(x))))

Derivative of activation:

---

lambda*(abs(y)*y*(1-y))

This did not converge for the mentioned training pattern (if I have not done anything wrong). Are there any suggestion please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **classification** problems, it is customary to use a sigmoid/logistic activation function in the output layer to get proper *probability* values in the range [0,1]; coupled with 1-of-N encoding for multi-class classification, each node output would represent the probability of the instance belonging to each class value.

On the other hand, if you have a **regression** problem, there is no need to apply additional functions on the output, and you can just take the raw linear combination output. The network will automatically learn the weights to give whatever output values you have (even in the thousands).

What you should also be careful about is to scale the *input features* (by normalizing all features to the range [-1,1] for example).

Comment: Hi thanks ! But in order to implement your suggestion for regression case how would I need to change my code, for example I am using back propagation where I have used derivative of the sigmoid in order to propagate the error .(http://www.speech.sri.com/people/anand/771/html/node37.html) , I used this algorithm , now if I do not use any sigmoid in output what will be delk in that case?  And if I only want to train the mentioned pattern in question, what type of topology will be better? Regression or Classification? I mean what would you do?

Comment: instead of the sigmoid activation function in the output layer, use the identity function `f(x) = x`. Also it is the target attribute you are trying to predict using the neural network that determines the type of problem you have: categorical/nominal values (classification, ex: classifying emails as spam/non-spam) vs. numeric values (regression, ex: predicting stock prices)..

Answer (score 2):

Scale the outputs up to the values you want, or normalize the training data back down to a range of [0,1] are the obvious solutions.  I can't think of any a priori reason that the scaling needs to be linear, either (although it obviously wants to be monotonically increasing) so you might tinker with log functions, here.

What kind of problem are you working on that you have such large ranges?

Comment: 1. Do I have to scale the every neuron's output? Or just the output neurons?                                                              2. If I normalize input do I have to normalize output also? and how to normalize output? along with input?                                                                3. How do I tinker with log function?                                                            4. My data is classified, I need to train that pattern mentioned in question, what would you suggest?

Comment: Your inputs are what they are; I would leave them alone.  What you're trying to do is match the range of outputs provided by your output neurons, to the values your training data dictates.  You can do this by either changing the transfer functions of the output neurons directly, or by scaling them up when needed, or by scaling the outputs dictated by the training data down.  In some sense these are all equivalent.  The neurons are left alone.